# Get Apache to create files as the web site owner

Tags: linux, apache, redhat, acl

I have a couple of PHP sites running on Apache hosted on Rocky 8 (Redhat). Each site has an owner e.g. mysite1admin, mysite2admin.

```
[root@MyWebServer01 ~]# ls -latrh /var/www/vhosts/
total 0
drwxrwsr-x. 6 root            webadmin 149 Jan 12  2023 .
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root            root      47 May 17  2023 ..
drwxrwsr-x. 6 mysite1admin webadmin  75 Nov 20 09:18 my-site-1.co.uk
drwxrwsr-x. 5 mysite2admin webadmin  63 Dec 21 16:00 my-site-2.co.uk
```

Apache (httpd) writes files (cache, logs) in each site but these files are owned by Apache.

Is there a way to get a process, in this case Apache, to create files as the owner of the directory e.g. mysite1admin ?

```
[root@MyWebServer01 ~]# ls -latrh /var/www/vhosts/my-site-1.co.uk/current/var/cache/prod/
total 376K
drwxrwsr-x+ 3 mysite1admin webadmin   18 Nov 20 09:18 ..
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 mysite1admin webadmin    0 Nov 20 09:18 App_KernelProdContainer.php.lock
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 mysite1admin webadmin  21K Nov 20 09:18 annotations.map
drwxrwsr-x+ 2 mysite1admin webadmin  28K Nov 20 09:18 ContainerYxkpfyH
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 mysite1admin webadmin  743 Nov 20 09:18 App_KernelProdContainer.php
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 mysite1admin webadmin 124K Nov 20 09:18 App_KernelProdContainer.php.meta
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 apache       webadmin 6.3K Nov 20 09:20 url_generating_routes.php.meta
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 apache       webadmin  36K Nov 20 09:20 url_generating_routes.php
```

Comment: No.  You can configure your Apache to switch to yser mysite1admin, but then all of apache would run under that user, which could be a problem.  The way to deal with this is to setup a directory stick bit for the group.  That way all new files inherit the group of the directory, and you set the permissions on the group.  ACLs might be required for more complex scenarios.  Another thing I have seen, though not recommended, is a cron job that runs every minute to perform a chown on the files.  Be careful that can create weird issues if not properly setup.